# How to slice Tensorflow network into two maintaining gradient back-propagation?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am trying to implement "Deep Convolutional Inverse Graphics Network" with tensorflow and it means that i have to do tricky things to the gradient.

Basically, i want to split an autoencoder into two independent networks. I don't have to, but that would be handy. The purpose is to apply some unspeakable modifications to the gradient flowing during the back propagation step. Do you have any ideas how it can be done? Here is a schema of what i want to achieve:
[image]

Easy to see, that for the forward path it means taking output of one network and plugging it into another. Unfortunately, I am not able to see how to backpropagate the error.

My best idea at the moment is to duplicate one of the weight matrixes i.e. copy W3 to the encder as W2.5 and than copy gradient of W3 as gradient of W2.5. But there must an easier way or an obvious misunderstanding in this schema.

Comment: One way you could do this is to embed your "non-TF" environment inside a Tensorflow operator. Tensorflow can then take care of propagating activations forward and gradients backwards. `tf.py_func` is one way to call non-Tensorflow from a Tensorflow graph; another way is to define a custom C++ operator. It is possible to define custom gradient functions for operators (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1095 for how to do it with a tf.py_func); your custom gradient can perform whatever unspeakable horrors you like.